# offlineimap : How to prevent moved messages to be marked as new after synchronization?

Tags: email, imap, offlineimap

I am using offlineimap 6.3.4 on a Debian system to synchronize my emails with two different IMAP servers (running Zimbra) and a MS Exchange server (through davmail). Everything is OK except the following.

When I move a read message from folder Foo (ie. message in folder directory Foo/cur with a :2,S extension) to folder Bar with my mailer (I check that it is indeed in Bar/cur with the :2,S extension) and run a synchronization the message appears as new again (ie. moved to Bar/new with :2, extension).

This is very annoying as the new message list is always cluttered by already read mails that have just been moved to other folders.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not: offlineimap only keeps track of changes to a given folder, assigning a sequence of UIDs to each message as it adds them to folders.  Moving a message to a different folder makes it use a new UID.

You can read more about these things in the [offlineimap FAQ](http://www.offlineimap.org/doc/FAQ.html):

- [What is the UID validity problem for folder?](http://www.offlineimap.org/doc/FAQ.html#what-is-the-uid-validity-problem-for-folder)
- [Can I copy messages between folders?](http://www.offlineimap.org/doc/FAQ.html#can-i-copy-messages-between-folders)